# Load balancing with only one server

Tags: apache, proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

The load balancing process indicated in this link :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

Is requiring **two servers** to work.

How can I adapt the described process to make it work with only **one server** ?

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of load balancing is to equally split traffic over a number of servers. Implementing load balancing with one server would be completely missing the point and entirely useless.

Comment: Yes I know that and you are right. But is it possible to make it work with only one server and what changes must be made ?

Comment: What purpose are you trying to implement load balancing on one server for? Just curious

Comment: So I can configure a reverse proxy for Apache.